# Trouble with opkg package manager in Angstrom embedded linux on Colibri module ARM v7 processor

Tags: package-management, upgrade, embedded, gcc, angstrom

I am working on a Colibri module having Angstrom linux installed in it! The processor is ARM v7. I am having trouble updating the softwares installed in the system.

Whenever I tried the command `opkg update`, I'd get a bunch of errors. Probably, it seems that the support from Angstrom project has been withdrawn as it gives `404 content not found` error.

The error message is:

```
$ opkg update
Downloading http://feeds.angstrom-distribution.org/feeds/v2014.06/ipk/eglibc/armv7ahf-vfp-neon/base/Packages.gz.
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Downloading http://feeds.angstrom-distribution.org/feeds/v2014.06/ipk/eglibc/armv7ahf-vfp-neon/debug/Packages.gz.
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Downloading http://feeds.angstrom-distribution.org/feeds/v2014.06/ipk/eglibc/armv7ahf-vfp-neon/gstreamer/Packages.gz.
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Downloading http://feeds.angstrom-distribution.org/feeds/v2014.06/ipk/eglibc/all/Packages.gz.
Inflating http://feeds.angstrom-distribution.org/feeds/v2014.06/ipk/eglibc/all/Packages.gz.
Updated list of available packages in /var/lib/opkg/lists/no-arch.
Downloading http://feeds.angstrom-distribution.org/feeds/v2014.06/ipk/eglibc/armv7ahf-vfp-neon/perl/Packages.gz.
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Downloading http://feeds.angstrom-distribution.org/feeds/v2014.06/ipk/eglibc/armv7ahf-vfp-neon/python/Packages.gz.
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Collected errors:
* opkg_download: Failed to download http://feeds.angstrom-distribution.org/feeds/v2014.06/ipk/eglibc/armv7ahf-vfp-neon/base/Packages.gz, wget returned 1.
* opkg_download: Failed to download http://feeds.angstrom-distribution.org/feeds/v2014.06/ipk/eglibc/armv7ahf-vfp-neon/debug/Packages.gz, wget returned 1.
* opkg_download: Failed to download http://feeds.angstrom-distribution.org/feeds/v2014.06/ipk/eglibc/armv7ahf-vfp-neon/gstreamer/Packages.gz, wget returned 1.
* opkg_download: Failed to download http://feeds.angstrom-distribution.org/feeds/v2014.06/ipk/eglibc/armv7ahf-vfp-neon/perl/Packages.gz, wget returned 1.
* opkg_download: Failed to download http://feeds.angstrom-distribution.org/feeds/v2014.06/ipk/eglibc/armv7ahf-vfp-neon/python/Packages.gz, wget returned 1.
404 Not Found
feeds.angstrom-distribution.org
```

Also, I tried installing package `gcc` by using the command `opkg install gcc`, but the same result. Again, surprisingly, the error message is unbelievable...

```
$ opkg install gcc
Unknown package 'gcc'.
Collected errors:
* opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package gcc.
```

I have no idea as to how to resolve this error as it is completely surprising. Also, it is of immense importance as I have to complete it within 2 days of installing `gcc` and running C programs...

Comment: I think you're having some other issue. I was able to browse to the angstrom-distribution.org website. There was no `Packages.gz` file in that directory but other directories around it had files.

Comment: @slm-that's what the problem is,there is no such file on their website,I couldn't find any directory! Would you mind providing links to those directories which contains files. Thanks for responding.

Comment: The URLs from above: http://feeds.angstrom-distribution.org/feeds/v2014.06/ipk/eglibc/armv7ahf-vfp-neon/machine/. I went up a level there and then under machines are subdirectories w/ package files etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I just saw your question now, and I had to deal with the same issue on Apalis T30. Toradex is quite helpful if you ask them questions, but I found the solution myself in their release notes.

Newer images of Toradex builds for Apalis and Colibri have an issue with the Angstrom package feeds. (V2.3 Beta1+ is my understanding). You will need to manually change some files in the /etc/opkg/*.conf to make it work. Search for armv7ahf-vfp-neon and replace them with armv7at2hf-vfp-neon. From Toradex's release notes file Colibri_T30_LinuxReleaseNotesV2.x.txt:

- The Angstrom-Distribution since switched to using ARM Thumb2 instruction set.
  To use their binary feeds e.g. using the opkg package manager please change in
  /etc/opkg/base-feed.conf et. al. armv7ahf-vfp-neon to armv7at2hf-vfp-neon.
  We consider switching in our next release.

On Apalis T30 I had to change 5-6 .conf files to make it work.

Comment: I did the same and I also got it successfully resolved a month ago. Thanks,but,I am unable to install `gcc` on that Colibri T-30 board,neither using native compilation,nor using Cross Compilation...

Comment: I installed packagegroup-sdk-target on my system (Apalis T30) with this V2.3 Beta2 and gcc works there.
http://developer.toradex.com/software-resources/arm-family/linux/features/native-compilation
As I recall I had to run the opkg install twice to make it install completely, not sure why.